# I get a black flicker from splash screen to my tab view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift & iOS.  I have a Storyboard based launch screen (white background with logo on it).  Then, the app launches either into a RootViewController which is a programmatic view controller that inherits from UIViewController.  It uses SnapKit.  It loads either loads login view, or tab bar view based on whether you're logged in or not.

For some reason, I see a black flicker.  Is this due to having no animations?  Or is it something else?  thank you.

Comment: RootViewController is based on a Storyboard?

Comment: No it is a programmatic view controller, inherits from UIViewController.

Comment: U had better post some code to get more info.

Comment: Going to be tough, proprietary codebase.  Should it not be using a storyboard for launch screen?